# Starting a new Android Activity in different task

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This is a bit of a convoluted story:

I have an `Activity A`. 
`Activity A` uses an intent to open a browser to do some authentication.
When this is done, the web page redirects to a URL. `Activity B` is set with an intent filter to be BROWSABLE, and the URL is such that the browser starts `Activity B` rather than opening a web page.

`Activity B` is therefore open, but as a 'child' of Chrome. In the recent apps window, I can see my original Activity A, then I can see `Activity B` under Chrome.

Any Activity I launch in Activity B seems to stay a child of Chrome. I have tried using the intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but this doesn't seem to change anything.

I would like to launch an Activity from Activity B that does not appear under Chrome, but under its own new task. Ideally, I would want to go back to the task that `Activity A` is in, but if this isn't possible a new one would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I've realised that this can be accomplished by using the singleTask launch mode as described here: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode

Essentially, I combined A and B into one activity, and set it to be a single task. When Chrome redirects to it, it returns to the original task rather than creating a new one as its child.